# MySQL won't allow VARCHAR as a Primary Key?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, unique, unique-constraint

I'm attempting to create a table called Students, with only one field, student_name.

student_name should be a VARCHAR and a primary key, because I want to uniquely identify students by their name.

```
CREATE TABLE 'swinters'.'Students' (
  'student_name' VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('student_name')
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

`MYSQL Error Number 1064`

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('student_name') ) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 2.

Comment: Are those single quotes a copy & paste error? If not, remove them. They are used to identify string literals. You must not use them for object names

Comment: Why all the votes to close?  Seems legitimate to me.

Comment: @EricJ. Look at the edit history on the question. Someone removed the OPs comment "Ahhhhhhh! Just figured it out! Sorry for being super noob! Need to change VARCHAR to VARCHAR(45) or the like. Wow, sorry for that!" Since the OP solved the problem on his own so quickly, I voted to close.

Comment: Also it's an incredibly simple and stupid issue.

Comment: I answered my own question immediately after I posted it, but my edit must have been removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the `VARCHAR(N)`, where `N` is the maximum string length

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide the length of the VARCHAR column. i.e. `VARCHAR(255)`

Answer (score 4):

mySQL **loves** you and it is trying to encourage you to do this right thing ;)

don't fight the right thing. Have two fields.

Use UNIQUE on your name field.

Use the primary key as just that.  Call it either `id` or `student_id`.

You can see a lot more info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232943/why-should-i-create-an-id-column-when-i-can-use-others-as-key-fields/8235024#8235024

Comment: Use UNIQUE and pray that John Smith doesn't enroll?

Comment: What about currencies table? Do you think it worth creating surrogate PK whereas `USD` or `GBP` already are unique and unchangeable.

Comment: @Michael Durrant: as long as you haven't it in your BL - it is surrogate, by definition. And I was speaking **specifically** about currencies for exchange rates project. So will you create *surrogate PK* for the table that keeps currencies names? What for?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: :-S is it so difficult to give an answer for the question?! :-( Will you create surrogate integer PK for currencies (yes/no)? What for? (I respect your experience, but I'm curious the **real** problems that business PK with currency can cause)

Comment: So you propose people to follow your general rule "Don't use a field that has 'any' business value or meaning as the primary key." but **in fact this rule has an exceptions**. And you agreed that the question **is not simple**. This confuses me :-S

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: what?! I just wanted to get the idea, why it is **necessary** to always create surrogates as you pointed out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232943/why-should-i-create-an-id-column-when-i-can-use-others-as-key-fields/8235024#8235024. But you started with links to wikipedia, which is just weird

Comment: @zerkms: I agree that every "rule" has exceptions, but why _not_ create surrogate integer PK for currencies?

Comment: @Herbert: why to do unnecessary steps? I prefer to perform the smallest possible amount of things to solve the issue (of course following some set of "best" practices). And in case of currencies example I don't see any reason in creating surrogate PK as long as it doesn't give us any benefits. Does it?

Answer (score 2):

You must specify how many chars the field will take like `VARCHAR(255)`